# Calcuation order value by considering dish and customer types

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the price of an order determined by the value of the dishes, type of dishes and the type of guest.

Dish Class:

```
public class DishImplementation implements Dish {

    private String name;
    private double basePrice;
    private DishType type;

    public DishImplementation(String name, double basePrice, DishType type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
        this.type = type;
        }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public double getBasePrice() {
        return basePrice;
    }

    @Override
    public DishType getDishType() {
        return type;
    }
```

Guest class:

```
public class GuestImplementation implements Guest {

    private String name;
    private GuestType type;

    public GuestImplementation (String name, GuestType type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public GuestType getGuestType() {
        return type;
    }
```

And here is the class I am having problems with, the Order class:

```
public class OrderImplementation implements Order {

    private Guest guest;
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    public OrderImplementation(Guest guest, List<Dish> dishes) {
        this.guest = guest;
        this.dishes = dishes;
    }

    @Override
    public double calculatePrice() {
        double price = 0;
        int i = 0;
        double total = 0;

        if ((getDishes().equals(DishType.MAIN_DISH)) || (getDishes().contains(DishType.DESSERT)) || (getDishes().contains(DishType.STARTER))) {
            for (Dish a : dishes) {
                Dish dish = dishes.get(i);
                price = dish.getBasePrice();
                total = total + price;
                i++;
            }
            return total = (total * this.guest.getGuestType().getDiscountFactor()) * 0.8;
        }
            else {
                for (Dish a : dishes) {
                    Dish dish = dishes.get(i);
                    price = dish.getBasePrice();
                    total = total + price;
                    i++;
                }
                return total = total * this.guest.getGuestType().getDiscountFactor();
            }
        }

    @Override
    public List<Dish> getDishes() {
        return dishes;
    }

    @Override
    public Guest getGuest() {
        return guest;
    }
}
```

The different DishTypes:

```
public enum DishType {
    STARTER, MAIN_DISH, DESSERT, OTHER;
}
```

My calculatePrice-method is working as intended (although I am sure it is overcomplicated, but that does not matter to me right now).

Only thing that does not work is, that it needs to apply a 20% discound to an order if it consists of at least one dish with the type MAIN_DISH, DESSERT or STARTER.

My approach is not working, since it always ignores my first if-condition.

And I also wonder why I can't call

```
dishes.getDishType();
```

just like I did with the GuestTypes. I am sure that would solve my problem.

Comment: Without reading all that code. `getDishes()` sounds like a list of dishes and you'r comparing to a single dish type. Doesn't "feel" right (but as I said, I didn't read all the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `dishes` is a list of `Dish` you need to iterate over them and check if type of any of them is `MAIN_DISH`, `DESSERT` or `STARTER`:

```
boolean shouldGetDiscount = false;
for (Dish dish : getDishes()) {
    DishType type = dish.getDishType();
    if (type.equals(DishType.MAIN_DISH) || type.equals(DishType.DESSERT) || type.equals(DishType.STARTER)) {
        shouldGetDiscount = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (shouldGetDiscount) {
    //consider the discount
}
```

> I acutally misread the instructions.. instead of getting an additional discount if it is a main, dessert OR starter, you only get the discount if it is a main, dessert AND starter.. how do you modify it so that it works that way instead?

```
boolean hasMain = false, hasStarter = false, hasDesert = false;
for (Dish dish : getDishes()) {
    DishType type = dish.getDishType();
    if (type.equals(DishType.MAIN_DISH))
        hasMain = true;
    else if (type.equals(DishType.DESERT))
        hasDesert = true;
    else if (type.equals(DishType.STARTER))
        hasStarter = true;

    if (hasMain && hasDesert && hasStarter)
        break;    
}
if (hasMain && hasDesert && hasStarter) {
    //consider the discount
}
```

Comment: I acutally misread the instructions.. instead of getting an additional discount if it is a main, dessert OR starter, you only get the discount if it is a main, dessert AND starter.. how do you modify it so that it works that way instead?